# I want to make a query based on the current logged in user id in Angular using firebase as my back-end

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, ref, uid

I've created a bookmarking feature which if the users clicks at the bookmark button the user's id will be save to that documents bookmark array in firebase which is working fine.

But i want to show all bookmarks by a user in the bookmark page/tab (it's a news site btw the documents have title, picture, article, bookmarks and so on kind of data).

I've got it to work manually

```js
bookmarks$: Observable<lajmiId[]>;
bookmarksBehaviorSubject : BehaviorSubject<string|null>;

constructor(
    private afs: AngularFirestore,
    public authService: AuthService,
    private ls: LoginService) {

this.bookmarksBehaviorSubject = new BehaviorSubject(null);
    this.bookmarks$ = this.bookmarksBehaviorSubject.pipe(
      switchMap(string => this.afs.collection<lajmiId>('lajmet', ref => 
        ref.where('bookmarks', 'array-contains', 'manually_written_uid')).valueChanges())
    );
}
```

Which works however when i try to pas in the uid dynamically based on the current logged in user it's not working,

```js
var uid = this.authService.userData.uid;

this.bookmarksBehaviorSubject = new BehaviorSubject(null);
    this.bookmarks$ = this.bookmarksBehaviorSubject.pipe(
      switchMap(string => this.afs.collection<lajmiId>('lajmet', ref => 
        ref.where('bookmarks', 'array-contains', uid)).valueChanges())
    );
```

This gives me an error of undefined since it's trying to read the uid before the data is ready to be used since the data is asynchronous.

I've tried putting the code in the ngOnInit() block same result.
I've tried creating an observable with the uid data still same result.
i just can't seem to figure this out.

My authServise looks something like this:

```js
import { User } from '../core/user';


export class AuthService {
    userData: Observable<any>;

    constructor(
    public afs: AngularFirestore,   // Inject Firestore service
    public afAuth: AngularFireAuth, // Inject Firebase auth service
    public router: Router,  
    public ngZone: NgZone, //ngZone service to move outside scope warning
    private dialogRef: MatDialog
    ) {
       this.afAuth.authState.subscribe(user => {
            if (user) {
                this.userData = user;
                localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(this.userData));
                JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));
            }
        })
    }
}
```

My User.ts contains the User interfase.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In your auth service you need to make the user as an Observable and then you can easily subsribe it on ngOnInit.

Suppose your auth.service.ts

```
export class AuthService{
   user$:Observable<any>;
 constructor(private router: Router,
          private afAuth: AngularFireAuth,
          private db:AngularFirestore,
          ) {
            this.user$ = this.afAuth.authState.pipe(
              switchMap(user => {
                if (user) {
//here you get the logged in user cred like uid
//you can use uid to refer in your collection
                  return this.afs.collection<lajmiId>(`lajmet/${user.uid}`).valueChanges()
                } else {
                  return of(null)
                }
              })
            )
          }
}
```

This will always give you the current logged in user and then you can easily subscribe after importing your authservice in the component you are trying to fetch.

```
this.authService.user$.take(1).subscribe(data=>{
//data of the user logged in
})
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but i'm having trouble implementing the changes due to the way i constructed my authservice should i redo the whole thing?

Comment: I wont suggest for redo, if u can share the code for auth(most of the app have common), I can suggest the changes
Note:you just have to set this user$ on the successful login and rest can work fine

Comment: Yeah you just have to replace the code in constructor and define user$:Observable on the top and let me know if you have error